# Modales Javascript

Tags: javascript, apache, cordova, modal

Hola buenas tengo un problema, y es que cuando abro una ventana modal con javascript, se me pone un fondo negro. El problema es que clickeo en el ese fondo negro y puedo operar como si no lo estuviese. Como puedo hacer para que esa parte de la zona negra alrededor de la modal, no se pueda hacer click? un saludo

```
 .filaRondasDesc, .filaAgrDesc {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 20em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.modalOverlay, .modalOverlay_update {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1111;
  backgroundcolor: #000;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1112;
  top: 47%;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hola Ruben. puedes mostrar tu codigo para contextualizarnos y sobre èl poder ayudarte? Si no, es muy amplio. Recuerda leer [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: No se que hacer ya, he jugado con el z-index pero nada.

Comment: Hace falta más código, el HTML y el css del `div` ese negro a ver como está hecho

Comment: Cuelga el html para poder ejecutarlo

Comment: tienes un error aqui: `backgroundcolor`. Debería ser `background-color` con guion, es posible que a partir de ahí el CSS falle.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `backdrop: 'static'` para bloquear el fondo.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#uploadedImagePopup').modal({
    show: true,
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: 'static'
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="modal fade modal-popup confirm-uploaded-image-popup" id="uploadedImagePopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-content modal-dialog modal-popup-content" role="document">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="confirm-uploaded-image-popup-img"></div>
          <div class="modal-popup-desc">You have uploaded a picture. Are you sure you want to add it to your gallery?</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-very-light-gray confirm-uploaded-image-popup-cancel">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-green confirm-uploaded-image-popup-ok">OK</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ruben de todas formas, al llamar a la modal, prueba backdrop: 'static'.

Comment: esta hecha con javascript, como llamo a eso?

Comment: jQuery. ¿Como llamas a tu modal? Pon el código entero, HTML+javascript, para que sea ejecutable.

Comment: Esto es lo que hago para sacar el fondo de atras var overlay_update = $(".modalOverlay_update");  overlay_update.show();